# Calculating the flux

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am a little unsure about setting the boundaries after I set up my equation.

The function is given as $F (x,y,z) = (x^{1/3}, - y^{1/3}$, and $2y/(x^{1/3}) )$

The surface it is over is given as $(x^{2/3}) + (y^{2/3}) + (z^{2/3}) = 4$ and it is in the first octant oriented upward.

**My thoughts:**

Since it has to be in the first octant, $z$ must be greater than $0$ and I rewrote the equation so that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and took the positive square root.

$z>0$ and $z = (4-x^{2/3}-y^{2/3})^{3/2}$

The equation for flux is given as the double integral of $-Pdz/dx - Qdz/dy + R dA$ over the region.

I took $P$ to be $x^{1/3}$, $Q$ to be $-(y)^{1/3}$ and $R$ to be $2y/(x^{1/3})$.

After I took the partials $w/r$ to each variable I put the equation together and the $P$ and $Q$ components canceled one another, leaving me with just $R.$

**Here's where I'm unsure**

I now have a double integral of $2y/(x^{1/3}) dA$. What I did was that I set $z = 0$ to look at the graphs "projection". I'm not sure if this is "legal". When doing so, I found the y equation to be $(4-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$

I then approached this via regular double integrals. I set the $x$bound from $0$ to $8$ and the $y$ bounds from $0$ to $(4-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$.

It yielded an answer of $32$, but I am very unsure if the whole projection idea is valid. Could someone clarify if this is how you approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you did seems just fine. Because $z$ is a function of $x,y$ in the domain you care about, the projection of the surface-piece onto the $z = 0$ plane is exactly the right domain of integration for $x,y$.

The only thing you might have missed is in writing $dA$. To find that, you need to think of the surface as parameterized by $S(x, y) = (x, y, z(x, y))$, and then write the integral as 
$$
\int \int \frac{2y}{x^\frac{1}{3}} ~~ \| \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial x}(x, y)\times \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial y}(x, y) \|~dx dy,
$$
and then write out everything and integrate (using the limits you wrote, but which I didn't bother to duplicate).

(Thanks for writing a clear question and saying what you'd tried!)